# JS: Call certain function before calling each of other functions in file

Tags: javascript, function

I have a question about better code reuse in JS.

E.g I have file `functions.js` with next functions:

```
export const a = ()=>{...}
export const b = ()=>{...}
export const c = ()=>{...}
....
const foo = ()=>{...}
```

I would like to call foo() function before each function in this class called.
The simple solution would be:

```
export const a = ()=>{foo() ...}
export const b = ()=>{foo() ...}
export const c = ()=>{foo() ...}
```

But what if i have more then 3 function?  How to optimise foo() function calls and call it each time before each file functions are called?

Comment: what is `foo` doing?

Comment: @brk It returns string value or null in my case

Comment: You should probably ask yourself what the trade off between readability and resuse is in a simple case like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `Proxy` where the target is one object with all of your functions, and then you could use `get` trap to catch every function call from that proxy. Then instead of exporting each function you could just export that proxy object.

```js
const a = (paramA, paramB) => console.log('a', paramA, paramB)
const b = () => console.log('b')
const c = () => console.log('c')

const foo = () => console.log('Foo')

const functions = new Proxy({a, b, c}, {
  get() {
    foo();
    return Reflect.get(...arguments);
  }
})

functions.a('foo', 'bar')
functions.c()
```

If you want to catch called function arguments and pass those arguments to `foo` you could return a proxy function from the get method where you have access to provided arguments and then inside you call foo and called function.

```js
const a = (paramA, paramB) => console.log('a', paramA, paramB)
const b = () => console.log('b')
const c = () => console.log('c')

const foo = (...params) => {
  console.log('Foo', params)
}

const functions = new Proxy({a, b, c}, {
  get(target, prop) {
    return function(...params) {
      foo(...params);
      target[prop].apply(null, params)
    }
  }
})

functions.a('foo', 'bar')
functions.c('baz')
```

Comment: Very interesting approach, but as you can see I call my functions from outside. How to implemented you approach if a(),b() and c() called from outer class/file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You export proxy object, then import it in file where you want to use those functions and then you just call them on imported proxy object. If you are importing those functions then you import them in one file, create the proxy and do the same process.

Comment: You can also do this `import {functions} from 'yourfile'`, `const {a, b, c} = functions` and then call them like `a(), b()` etc...

Comment: Another small question, if foo() should get parameters that are sent to those functions?

Comment: I guess you could do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/oxfjLw4v/, return params from Foo and the bind those params to your function though `this`. Note that in that case you cannot use arrow functions.

Comment: I mean you call functions.a('foo', 'bar'), how to pass those params inside get() to foo()... get(){foo(...passed to a func params)}

Comment: Your first snippet doesn't call `foo` when the functions are called, but when the object properties are accessed. Your second snippet does better in that regard, but it should not use a `Proxy` - just create a plain object of closures, there's no reason to dynamically generate function on every property access of arbitrary properties.

Comment: @Bergi I agree with the first part, didn't consider that, but `plain object of closures` what do you mean, and how are you going to dynamically intercept every function call without creating the getter for each one?

Comment: @NenadVracar I wouldn't do it dynamically (on property access - with getters or proxies) at all. The functions are known beforehand, when you put them in the exported object. Just loop through them, like in AbanaClara's second snippet.

Comment: @NenadVracar `bind` still creates a new function on every call

Comment: @Bergi We could do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/rjwp4hcf/, but at that point I would't use proxy.

Comment: @NenadVracar That's what I was saying all the time - that you shouldn't use a proxy :-)

Answer (score 2):

<s>You can use classes, extend `Foo` and run a super() on the constructor.</s>

```
class Foo {
   constructor(){
     //do something
   }
}

export class A extends Foo {
   constructor(){
      super();
   }
}

export class B extends Foo {
   constructor(){
      super();
   }
}
```

But all in all, it's almost just the same as calling `Foo()` over and over again. You still have to explicitly write the super and extends for each function.

> But what if i have more then 3 function? How to optimise foo() function calls and call it each time before each file functions are called?

There is just no issues calling `Foo()` for each function. It's not like you are dynamically creating your function and have to find a way to decorate it somehow.

But hey you can add all your functions into an iterable and decorate `foo()` on them before you export.

```
const foo = ()=>{ console.log('foo') }
const a = ()=>{console.log('a');}
const b = ()=>{console.log('b')}
const c = ()=>{console.log('c')}

//make sure to create the collection which we will iterate later on.
//you can also implicitly add the functions here instead
const collection = {a, b, c}; 


//this runs at the bottom of the script
const obj = {};
for(let col in collection){
    obj[col] = function(f){
       return (args) => {
          foo(args); f(args);
       }
    }(collection[col]);
}

//then export
export obj;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my case it is not class but simple JS file with functions. Is Class is only solution?

Comment: @AlexBerd Nothing that I know of, or nothing much more simpler than what I suggested or what you have in your original post.

Comment: I tried to create also solution with currying approach, but no luck :{ . Thanks for your help

Comment: I would upvote if you removed the first part of the answer with the horrible `class` stuff :-)

Comment: @Bergi I understand the distaste for the `class` syntax in this scenario, but it's STILL one way and I believe it doesn't hurt putting it in there.

Comment: @AbanaClara Tbh I don't even completely understand how you intended this to work. A `class` cannot replace a function (especially an arrow function, like the OP had used), and having to explicitly call `super()` in every subclass is at least as bad as having to explicitly call `foo()` in every function. OP wanted to remove that duplication and make his code shorter.

Comment: @Bergi Heh, good point actually. I have it mentioned that it is the same as writing `foo()` for every function.

Comment: @AbanaClara Yeah, since you noticed it yourself I was having an even harder time to understand why you still considered  `class` an improvement.

Comment: @Bergi more like a variant haha

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the functions you have in another function which will call `foo` before invoking the original function.

Here in the snippet below, I have put all the functions in an array and using `Array.prototype.map` I have created another function wrapper which invokes the `foo` function and returns the wrapped functions in a new array:
:

```js
const a = ()=>{
    console.log("a")
}
const b = ()=>{
    console.log("b")
}
const c = ()=>{
    console.log("c")
}
const foo = ()=>{
    console.log("foo");
}

function wrap(funArr, foo) {
     return funArr.map((fun) => {
        return function() {
            foo();
            fun();
        }            
    });
}
for( let f of wrap([a, b, c], foo)){
    f();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use higher order functions to derive other and thus re-use the code. Simple case:

```
//your functions as they appear currently but you won't export them that way.
const _a = ()=>{...}
const _b = ()=>{...}
const _c = ()=>{...}

const foo = ()=>{...}

//this will take two functions and generate a new one that calls the second before the first
const myDecorator = (mainFn, preCallFn) => () => { preCallFn(); return mainFn(); }

//now decorated and export the functions
export const a = myDecorator(_a, foo);
export const b = myDecorator(_b, foo);
export const c = myDecorator(_c, foo);
```

This way you don't have to change what the `a` (or `_a` in this case) function does at all and you can *change* what your exported function does without touching either `foo` or `_a` - say, you can later decide that `a = myDecorator(_a, bar)` but leave everything else in place. Or maybe you change to a different decorator that calls the `foo` function *after* `_a`. In all cases, you only have to change one thing and it's not the logic of your functions. They don't know nor care about each other.

A more generalised decorator might look like this

```
//take one main function and any number of things to call before it
const decorator = (mainFn, ...preCallFns) => {
  //generate a new function with any number of arguments
  return function(...args) {
    //call each function that you want to call before
    preCallFns.forEach(fn => fn());

    //call the decorated function forwarding any arguments and the current context
    return mainFn.apply(this, args)
  }
}
```

This is more robust and will allow more flexibilty - you can accept functions with or without arguments and it would still work. An even better idea is to use currying:

```
//take the functions first and the function to decorate second
const decorator = (...preCallFns) => mainFn => {
  return function(...args) {
    preCallFns.forEach(fn => fn());

    return mainFn.apply(this, args)
  }
}
```

Now you can do reusable decorators, for example:

```
const firstDecorator = decorator(foo);
const secondDecorator = decorator(bar);
const thirdDecorator = decorator(foo, bar);

export const a = firstDecorator(_a);
export const b = firstDecorator(_b);
export const c = firstDecorator(_c);
export const d = secondDecorator(_d);
export const e = secondDecorator(_e);
export const f = thirdDecorator(_f);
```

The advantage here is that you can alter the decorators without changing any logic. For example, you can change `firstDecorator` to instead be `decorator(foo, bar, baz)` and you don't need to alter anything. You know that `a`, `b`, and `c` still need the same common logic to be run, so they still use `firstDecorator` but you don't change *how* they are made - you've just changed the decorator. However, since the decorator itself is merely a list of functions to call before the main function, then you haven't actually changed any logic in it, either. Just how it's derived - by using a different list of functions to call. Your code is decoupled, and generic, thus the entire difference is a list of arguments you supply. Everything would still work and would still be easy to understand and test.

---

If you're using Lodash, then you can instead use [`_.wrap`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#wrap) which is even more flexible, as it allows you to define any wrapping function:

```
const _a = ()=>{...}
const _b = ()=>{...}
const _c = ()=>{...}

const foo = ()=>{ ... }

const wrapper = (fn, ...args) => { foo(); return fn(...args); }

export const a = _.wrap(_a, wrapper);
export const b = _.wrap(_b, wrapper);
export const b = _.wrap(_b, wrapper);
```

If you prefer a curried version similar to what my last custom example did, then  can use the [FP version of Lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) and then the invocation will look like this

```
const fooDecorator = _.wrap(wrapper);

export const a = fooDecorator(_a);
```

Or if you already have the normal version of Lodash, then you can can just make your own FP version of `_.wrap`:

```
const fpWrap = _.curry(_.rearg(_.ary(_.wrap, 2), [1, 0]));

const fooDecorator = fpWrap(wrapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use a **dictionary**

```
// Functions.js 
export const a = ()=>{...}
export const b = ()=>{...}
export const c = ()=>{...}
....
const foo = ()=>{...}

const dictionary = {a,b,c,d}
export const callAfterFoo = (...args) => {
   const funcName = args[0] // Name of the function to call
   args.shift() // Remove funcName from the list of arguments passed in callAfterFoo
   try {
     foo()
     dictionary[funcName].apply(this, args)
   }
   catch (e) {
     throw new Error(`Function by the name ${funcName} does not exist: ${e}`)
   }
}



// Main.js 
import { callAfterFoo } from './functions.js'

callAfterFoo('a', param1, param2)
```

Comment: Why not pass the *functions* instead of their *names* that you then have to look up? What does that gain you?

Comment: Hi, Vlaz. Since those functions are not 'default exports', you have to look up the name of the functions anyhow to import those. And to pass the function itself in the callAfterFoo() function in Main.js file you would also have to import those functions explicitly in Main.js which I believe is not really necessary in this case.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `async` `await`

like

```
export const a = async ()=>{ await foo() ...}
export const b = async ()=>{ await foo() ...}
export const c = async ()=>{ await foo() ...}
```

Comment: Why though ...?

Comment: @Misbauddin Chowdhury I am trying to avoid calling foo() in each function in any way sync or async